# networkmanager-openconnect with flag --no-http-keepalive not possible to set in UI

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openconnect

I activated the VPN SSL on our Cisco RV340 router. I want to use openconnect to establish the vpn connection. When I use the CLI in my bash session it is working when using the flag `--no-http-keepalive`.

I now wanted to config the connection in the networkmanager with the networkmanager-openconnect-gnome on my xubuntu system. But there is no option to set the `--no-http-keepalive` flag.

Is there any chance that I can set this flag over the config wizard in the networkmanager plugin?